# How can I play a video from splash screen in main page?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have two html files, one is Splash screen and another is main.

The splash have a `Go!` button so clicking will redirect user to main.

How can I play a video in main, once I click on `Go!` button?
For some reason I cant use *autoplay* in the main.

Here is the Splash Screen code :

```js
function myFunction() {
    window.open("themes/default/main.html");
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()" >
    <button>Go!</button>
</div>
```

And a simple code for `main.html`:

```
<video muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="xmb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the words 'controls autoplay' in the video tag as given below.

```
<video muted loop id="myVideo" controls autoplay>
    <source src="xmb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason I cant use autoplay in the main.

You could use this code in main.html before body tag

```
<script>
 document.getElementById('myVideo').play();
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
 document.getElementById('myVideo').setAttribute("autoplay", "true");
</script>
```

**Another method**

Play video only if you are opening from splash. Pass a parameter in url and check of that in main.html.

```
function myFunction() {
    window.open("themes/default/main.html?play=1");
}
```

In main.html

```
<script>
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};

if (getUrlParameter('play' == '1') {
 document.getElementById('myVideo').play();
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in your splash screen code function to

```
function myFunction() {
 window.open("themes/default/main.html?s=autoplay");
}
```

and add your main.html to

```
<script>
   var status = window.location.search.substring(3);
   if (status == 'autoplay')
   {
    var vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');
    vid.play();
   }
</script>
```